# Qt Console Application crasshes due to setLocalCertificate for a QSslSocket

Tags: qt, ssl

Need to create a small server application that uses SSL to connect to a client. There can only be one client connected at a time.

Every time a a new connection is attempted by the client, the following function is called:

```
void Control::on_newConnection() {

    if (socket != nullptr) return;

    logger.appendStandard("New connection received 0");

    // New connection is available.
    socket = (QSslSocket*)(listener->nextPendingConnection());

    logger.appendStandard("New connection received 1");

    if (!socket->isValid()) {
        logger.appendError("ERROR: Could not cast incoming socket connection");
        return;
    }

    logger.appendStandard("New connection received 2");

    // Doing the connections.
    connect(socket,SIGNAL(encrypted()),this,SLOT(on_encryptedSuccess()));
    connect(socket,SIGNAL(sslErrors(QList<QSslError>)),this,SLOT(on_sslErrors(QList<QSslError>)));
    connect(socket,SIGNAL(stateChanged(QAbstractSocket::SocketState)),this,SLOT(on_socketStateChanged(QAbstractSocket::SocketState)));
    connect(socket,SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)),this,SLOT(on_socketError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));
    connect(socket,&QSslSocket::readyRead,this,&Control::on_readyRead);
    connect(socket,&QSslSocket::disconnected,this,&Control::on_disconnected);

    logger.appendStandard("New connection received 3");

    // The SSL procedure.
    socket->setPrivateKey(":/certificates/server.key");
    logger.appendStandard("New connection received 3.1");
    socket->setLocalCertificate(":/certificates/server.csr");
    logger.appendStandard("New connection received 3.2");
    socket->setPeerVerifyMode(QSslSocket::VerifyNone);
    logger.appendStandard("New connection received 3.2");
    socket->startServerEncryption();

    logger.appendStandard("New connection received 4");

}
```

The server is an application that is left running, listening for connections. Once a connection is established I do stuff depending on what the client asks and then delete the connection with this function.

```
void Control::clearSocket(const QString &fromWhere){
    if (socket != nullptr){
        logger.appendStandard(fromWhere + ": About to delete socket");
        delete socket;
        socket = nullptr;
        logger.appendStandard(fromWhere + ": Socket deleted!");
    }
}
```

This works perfectly the very first time the client makes a request. Teh connection is established, the server receives the request and the client receives the answer, then the connection in the server is deleted when the client closes it.

However when I want to do the exact same transaction the second time, the server program crashes on this line:

```
    socket->setLocalCertificate(":/certificates/server.csr");
```

I know this due to the log meesages.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Are you executing a slot called by signal from `socket` when you `delete` the same socket? You can check this for example by setting breakpoint in the delete line, and seeing the call stack.

Comment: I don't think this was the case. I had a problem similar to this before and managed to solve it. What I did is bypass the problem by using a trick. But I didn't paste it as an answer, because it is not technically a solution and was pressed for time

Answer (score 0):

Probably something in the event queue related to a deleted QObject based socket object causes the crash.

To safely delete use [socket->deleteLater()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#deleteLater) instead of calling delete directly. It schedules the object for deletion through event loop and any pending events for the object will be removed from the event queue.

Comment: Do you suspect that this is what is causing the problem?

Comment: @aarelovich Did changing delete to deleteLater fix the problem? If not, then you had also some other issue in your code. Anyway, direct delete was a bug in your code which could cause seg fault.

Comment: I've never tried it because, I solved the problem some other way. And since the code is now working and currently running, i don't want to modify it. However I do realize that what I did is a workaround and not a REAL answer to the problem. Should I go ahead and close this question or something to that effect?